# R: one side truncated mean

Tags: r

I'm new to R and this forum so sorry for stupid questions.

I have a set of reaction time data (~200 responses per participant) but before calculating the mean I want to define the 10% slowest responses of each participant as outliers and cut them off.

For example: If i have 20 values I want to cut off the 2 slowest of them (=10%)...

I feel like there should be an easy way to do so in R, but I have no idea how to start.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use quantile to help with this.  For example:

```
data <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10)

mean(data)
> 5.5

#Restrict to data that is above 10th percentile
mean(data[data > quantile(data, .10)]) 
> 6
```

Comment: Sorry, but I must be misunderstanding.  quantile(data, .10) will cut off the lowest 10% of values.  For example, if I extend data to include 1-20 and run `data[data > quantile(data, .10)]`, I'll see 1 and 2 aren't included in that data.  Now, if you want the data _stored_ without the lowest 10%, I'd have to store it back like so: `data <- data[data > quantile(data, .10)]`.  Not sure if this is what you're after, so if it isn't, just let me know!

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks a lot again. I've already deleted my comment because I didn't consider my data structure. Of course you are right! thanks again.

Comment: Do you know if there is a possibility to calculate the quantile depending on values in a different column? I have long format data and I want to cut of the slowest 10% of each participant (not the entire column of response time values). I didn't take this into account when posting my question. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the answer is yes, but I'm not 100% sure without seeing an idea of what you're looking at.  Could you post a small example of the data you're dealing with, and what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

@ Sam: 
My Problem is as follows... If we have a data frame like the one below. I want to cut off the slowest 10 %  of each participant which would be "11" for subject_no 1 and "7" for subject_no 2 
The question is: How can I take the subject.no into account when using the quantile function you suggested?

```
[subject.no] [response.time] 

[1,]    1    11    
[2,]    1    0    
[3,]    1    9    
[4,]    1    9   
[5,]    2    7    
[6,]    2    0    
[7,]    2    3    
[8,]    2    3
```

Comment: If I set `data <- data.frame(subject.no = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
           response.time = c(11, 0, 9, 9, 7, 0, 3, 3))` Try using `ddply(data, .(subject.no), subset, response.time < quantile(response.time, .9))`  That returns the data set without the 11 for subject1 and the 7 for subject2.  (Assuming you've installed the plyr library)